# Dedication of Clarke's "Imperial Earth"

Tags: novel, history-of, arthur-c-clarke

Arthur C. Clarke's 1976 novel *Imperial Earth* is dedicated

> For a lost friend

and has this Hemingway quote on the dedication page

> Remember them as they were; and write them off.

Is the backstory behind this dedication known?

Comment: I feel the need to say that if someone makes a cryptic dedication like that they clearly didn't want the meaning known.  Maybe we should respect that and not feel the need to open their soul after they die.

Comment: Given that the dedication is public knowledge, I think it is fair game to try and work out its meaning. I would imagine that it refers to Clarke's rift with Mike Wilson, but this is only speculation